# Select / Update records in one table that are LIKE words selected from another table column with multiple records

Tags: mysql

I need to find records in product.title that are like one of many words. Currently this is done by a long query like this one:

```
Select product.product_id, product.name from product WHERE product.name like '%word1%' OR product.name like '%word2%' OR product.name like '%word3%', etc (too many words).
```

Decided to put these words in a new table for easier management and build a query with the records from that table

```
TABLE banned_words.word
word1
word2
word3
etc
```

I tried GROUP_CONCAT with a separator before and after banned_words.word so that I can use it in a sub-query, but the result was larger than the 1024 characters limit. I don't suppose I can use a join with a sub-string

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT product.product_id, product.name
FROM   product
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   banned_words
               WHERE  product.name LIKE CONCAT('%', word, '%')
```